# Rblpapi for several securities with different start.date end.date

Tags: r, bloomberg, rblpapi

I recently started using Rblpapi. I think it is a lot easier to use than the Python counterparts. 
I have a Ddata frame with bond issuance dates and maturity dates, and I would like to extract all the daily yields between those two dates, for all the bonds in my sample. This would require to either specify start/end dates as a vector, or use `sapply` for each row in my data frame:

```
       cusip   issuance        mat
1: 000361AA3 10/24/1989 11/01/2001
2: 000361AB1 10/12/1993 10/15/2003
3: 00077DAB5 01/07/1994 01/12/1996
4: 00077DAF6 07/27/1994 08/01/2009
5: 00077TAA2 05/20/1993 05/15/2023
```

My understanding is that I can only specify start/end dates as a character. My first approach was to put a very early start.date and a very late end.date such that all the bond trades for all the bonds in the sample would be between these two dates:

```
require(data.table)
require(Rblpapi)

con <- blpConnect()

cusips <- c('00077DAB5 Corp', '00077DAF6 Corp', '44891AAF4 Corp' )
col <- "YLD_YTM_MID"
sdate <- as.Date("1985-01-01") #early date
edate <- as.Date("2017-04-01") #late date
periods <- c("periodicitySelection"="DAILY")

data <- bdh(sym, col, 
            start.date=sdate,end.date = edate, options=periods, con = con)
```

This however, gave me the following error:

```
Error: Choice sub-element not found for name 'securityData'.
```

I would assume the next best alternative is to use `sapply`

Comment: Your code worked for me. The only thing I changed was sym for cusips. 00077DAB5 comes back empty though. It's a matured bond. I don't think you can get historical YLD_YTM_MID on these matured bonds. I'm using Rblpapi_0.3.5

Comment: @PLapointe running the code above I get the following message. I assume that Bloomberg gives an error if I request data before/after the life of the bond? : Error in bdh_Impl(con, securities, fields, start.date, end.date, options,  : 
  Choice sub-element not found for name 'securityData'.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. I pasted my code and result below. Again, the only thing I changed was `sym` to `cusips` in the `bdh` call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code I run that works:

```
require(data.table)
require(Rblpapi)

con <- blpConnect()

cusips <- c('00077DAB5 Corp', '00077DAF6 Corp', '44891AAF4 Corp' )
col <- "YLD_YTM_MID"
sdate <- as.Date("1985-01-01") #early date
edate <- as.Date("2017-04-01") #late date
periods <- c("periodicitySelection"="DAILY")

data <- bdh(cusips, col, #changed sym to cusips
            start.date=sdate,end.date = edate, options=periods, con = con)
str(data)

List of 3
 $ 00077DAB5 Corp:'data.frame': 0 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ date       :Class 'Date'  int(0) 
  ..$ YLD_YTM_MID: num(0) 
 $ 00077DAF6 Corp:'data.frame': 247 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ date       : Date[1:247], format: "1997-11-18" "1997-11-19" "1997-11-20" ...
  ..$ YLD_YTM_MID: num [1:247] 6.77 6.74 6.77 6.74 6.77 ...
 $ 44891AAF4 Corp:'data.frame': 262 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ date       : Date[1:262], format: "2016-03-16" "2016-03-17" "2016-03-18" ...
  ..$ YLD_YTM_MID: num [1:262] 2.92 2.93 2.88 2.92 2.94 ...
```

Comment: Odd. Copying your code directly still gives me the same error message. I am also using Rblpapi_0.3.5

Comment: Works for me too.  @dleal you _may_ have certain settings at your terminal which prevent this from working.

Comment: @PLapointe: Correct answer but you can remove the `data.table` load here...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Yes, absolutely. I just wanted to show OP that running the code exactly as he wrote it worked for me. I don't use data.table.  More of a dplyr guy...

Comment: Well, I am more on the data.table side which is why you see it in Rblpapi :)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel  This is odd. Yesterday it was working, but currently, even the examples in the vignettes give the same error. The only thing I did differently was that yesterday I submitted a large request using the same code as above but with tens of thousands of tickers. Maybe I exceeded some of the daily Bloomberg limits.

Comment: @PLapointe thank you for verifying the code works. I also worked for me yesterday

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel  will accept the answer as it has been verified correct. However, my only remaining concern is if putting a start.date to the issuance of the bond and an end.date after maturity is expected to give an error or NAs. I would prefer NAs

Comment: Daily limits excess can turn into weekly / monthly issues.  That is "them", not us in the package.  Contact the Bbg help desk.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel effectively, I had exceeded the monthly limit for my requests. I tried it on a different terminal and worked perfectly. Thank you.